# Jmeter User Defined Variable not able to pass a parameter as a value

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to define a user defined variable to a value of my correlation variable count, but its not passing the value.

Name: numOfDoc

Value: ${doc_ID1_matchNr}

I also tried to eval. Has anyone experienced the same problem? How did you solve? I would like to learn.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

> The User Defined Variables element lets you define an **initial set of variables**, just as in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan).

So you can use User Defined Variables for example to:

- create a "global" variable to hold stuff like endpoint address, protocol, port for using in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers
- generate dynamic parameters like [current timestamp](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)

The main idea is to define a set of variables which can be used everywhere in test plan so if you will need to change a value in the future, i.e. to run the test against another environment you would be able to do it in one place only and won't have to change each and every value in each and every Sampler.

More information: [Using User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)